# Sum of first elements in nested lists

Tags: python, list, numbers

I am trying to get the first element in a nested list and sum up the values.

eg.

```
nested_list = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]
print sum(i[0] for i in nested_list)
```

However, there are times in which the first element in the lists `None` instead

```
nested_list = [[1, 'a'], [None, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]
new = []
for nest in nested_list:
    if not nest[0]:
        pass
    else:
        new.append(nest[0])
print sum(nest)
```

Wondering what is the better way that I can code this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just *filter* then, in this case testing for values that are not `None`:

```
sum(i[0] for i in nested_list if i[0] is not None)
```

A generator expression (and list, dict and set comprehensions) takes any number of nested `for` loops and `if` statements. The above is the equivalent of:

```
for i in nested_list:
    if i[0] is not None:
        i[0]  # used to sum()
```

Note how this mirrors your own code; rather than use `if not ...: pass` and `else`, I inverted the test to only allow for values you actually can sum. Just add more `for` loops or `if` statements in the same left-to-right to nest order if you need more loops with filters, or use `and` or `or` to string together multiple tests in a single `if` filter.

In your specific case, just testing for `if i[0]` would also suffice; this would filter out `None` and `0`, but the latter value would not make a difference to the sum anyway:

```
sum(i[0] for i in nested_list if i[0])
```

You already approached this in your own `if` test in the loop code.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Python has **no `null`**, the equivalent of `null` in languages like Java, C#, JavaScript, etc. is `None`.

Secondly, we can use a filter in the generator expression. The most generic is probably to check with `numbers`:

```
from numbers import Number

print sum(i[0] for i in nested_list if isinstance(i[0], Number))
```

`Number` will usually make sure that we accept `int`s, `long`s, `float`s, `complex`es, etc. So we do not have to keep track of all objects in the Python world that are numerical ourselves.

Since it is also possible that the list contains *empty* sublists, we can also check for that:

```
from numbers import Number

print sum(i[0] for i in nested_list if i and isinstance(i[0], Number))
```